# Print LinkedHashMap in table format

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am looking for better algorithm to print a LinkedHashMap in table format by its key.
I explain scenario here,

```
//hashmap goes like this
LinkedHashMap<String , ArrayList<String>> hash=new LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

// put some values in some arraylist
ArrayList<String> value1=Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
ArrayList<String> value2=Arrays.asList("s4", "s5", "s6");
ArrayList<String> value1=Arrays.asList("s7", "s8", "s9");

// put values in hashmap
hash.put("key1",value1);
hash.put("key2",value2);
hash.put("key3",value3);
```

Now, i wish output should be like this in `html` table.

```
key1 key2 key3

s1    s4   s7

s2    s5   s6

s3    s6   s9
```

what is good way to do this? thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // hashmap goes like this
        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> hash = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // put some values in some arraylist
        List<String> value1 = (List<String>) Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
        List<String> value2 = (List<String>) Arrays.asList("s4", "s5", "s6");
        List<String> value3 = (List<String>) Arrays.asList("s7", "s8", "s9");

        // put values in hashmap
        hash.put("key1", value1);
        hash.put("key2", value2);
        hash.put("key3", value3);

        int count = 0;
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            for (String key : hash.keySet()) {
                String value = hash.get(key).get(count);
                System.out.printf("\t" + value);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
            count++;
            if (count == hash.get("key1").size()) {
                exit = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

And following is the output as desired:

```
s1  s4  s7
s2  s5  s8
s3  s6  s9
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Just did some typecasting and it worked . thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **JSP** page, try this

LinkedHashMap> hash=new LinkedHashMap>();

```
// put some values in some arraylist
ArrayList<String> value1=Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
ArrayList<String> value2=Arrays.asList("s4", "s5", "s6"); 
ArrayList<String> value1=Arrays.asList("s7", "s8", "s9");

// put values in hashmap
hash.put("key1",value1);
hash.put("key2",value2);
hash.put("key3",value3);
```

```
<% 
  for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> en: hash.entrySet()) {
      %>
   <td> 
     <% en.getKey(); %>
   </td>
 <%  }
 %>
 </td>
  </tr>
```

you can also do this using JSTL tags.

Comment: this only prints the `LinkedHashMap` keys, not the values in the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
 sb.append("<tr>");
 sb.append("<td>" + hash.get("key1").get(0) + "</td>");
 sb.append("<td>" + hash.get("key2").get(0) + "</td>");
 sb.append("<td>" + hash.get("key3").get(0) + "</td>");
 sb.append("</tr>");
```